# Using integers/dates as terminals in NLTK parser

Tags: python, regex, parsing, nltk, earley-parser

I'm trying to use the Earley parser in NLTK to parse sentences such as:

*If date is before 12/21/2010 then serial = 10*

To do this, I'm trying to write a CFG but the problem is I would need to have a general format of dates and integers as terminals, instead of the specific values. 
Is there any ways to specify the right hand side of a production rule as a regular expression, which would allow this kind of processing?

Something like:

```
S -> '[0-9]+'
```

which would handle all integers.

Comment: Your date format is locale dependant. And mainly is ambigous (collide with a mathematical expression 12 div 21 div 2010 which is probably not that you want

Comment: You're right but that will be easy to handle since the input will never contain any mathematical expressions like what you mentioned. Also the date format will be fixed, say, MM/DD/YYYY. I found a way to handle integers, but I'm still looking for a proper solution for dates.

Answer (score 2):

For this to work, you'll need to tokenize the date so that each digit and slash is a separate token.

```
from nltk.parse.earleychart import EarleyChartParser
import nltk

grammar = nltk.parse_cfg("""
DATE -> MONTH SEP DAY SEP YEAR
SEP -> "/"
MONTH -> DIGIT | DIGIT DIGIT
DAY -> DIGIT | DIGIT DIGIT
YEAR -> DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT
DIGIT -> '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9' | '0'
""")

parser = EarleyChartParser(grammar)
print parser.parse(["1", "/", "1", "0", "/", "1", "9", "8", "7"])
```

The output is:

```
(DATE
  (MONTH (DIGIT 1))
  (SEP /)
  (DAY (DIGIT 1) (DIGIT 0))
  (SEP /)
  (YEAR (DIGIT 1) (DIGIT 9) (DIGIT 8) (DIGIT 7)))
```

This also affords some flexibility in the form of allowing dates and months to be single-digit.